# Windows 8.1 not allowing me to install ISP's (Tata Photon) client software for Huawei EC315 USB modem. Need to Auto run the setup file

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-8.1, modem, autorun

Well, as it says in the question above, I need to install my service provider's client software to connect to the internet. According to the instructions the ISP (Tata 
photon) gave me, I'm to find the Auto Run icon in My computer when I plug in my device. But, When I do that,Windows automatically installs the wrong drivers. I'm unable to see the icon in "This PC". I went to Device manager and uninstalled the device (The delete driver check box was not visible when uninstalling) and restarted my laptop.

I plugged the device in, but before I could do anything, within seconds, Windows re installed the  wrong drivers again. I went into control panel and found something called Mobile Broadband HL Service from Huawei Technologies Co.,Ltd. I uninstalled it and plugged the device back in. This time, for the first time, the dialog box popped up asking me what I want Windows to do with the device. I selected Auto run, but then, nothing happened. I went back to control panel to find the software re installed itself automatically. I uninstalled it again.

This time, when the device was plugged in, I could see the icon in 'This PC' and the dialog box. I selected auto run and a  UAC dialog box popped up asking me if I want to install the software. I click yes, but nothing happened and I could not see the icon in "This PC" anymore.